# How do duplicated expressions effect the performance of queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

When I write something like

```
SELECT Cast(DateDiff(milliseconds, col1, col2) / DateDiff(milliseconds, col3, col4) as int as [Result] 
FROM [sometable]
WHERE Cast(DateDiff(milliseconds, col1, col2) / DateDiff(milliseconds, col3, col4) as int > 4
```

Is that inefficient and how to do it better?

Comment: Efficiency you can see in query plan. I'm pretty sure that most sql servers should calculate such expressions only once. Another thing is readability - I would make inner query with normal column names and select all records from it and apply where condition there. Again sql servers should internally create same plan, but query looks better and has single expression to fix it afterwards :)

Comment: The query won't be SARGable, so that would result in a full scan of the table; that *would* be "inefficient". The only way to change that, however, would be with computed columns that are `PERSISTED` and have appropriate indexes.

Comment: Side note, your query has multiple typographical error; the [first parameter for `DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) should be the singular form, not plural, and you don't close your parathesis for your `CAST` functions.

Comment: @Larnu - one other general case option is to have an actual column with a CHECK constraint and those same appropriate index that guarantees the value meets the expression criteria; in both cases, the value is guaranteed by the DB engine to be accurate on every INSERT or UPDATE, they just accomplish it in different ways.  I find the PERSISTED and indexed computed column is a simpler and more transparent, but it's not the only way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that inefficient?

No, SQL Server will evaluate the expression once and re-use it.

> how to do it better?

You can *laterally join* a re-usable values with a *cross apply* and a *values* table constructor:

```
Select MyValue, OtherCols
from SomeTable
cross apply(values( <my expression> ))v(MyValue)
where MyValue = ?;
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by inefficient, I suppose. Will the data engine run the expression twice? No. Will the query get an efficient query plan? Unlikely, as the expression isn't SARGable.

Comment: Yes, I was addressing only the duplication of (any) expression, not the specific expression used, the OP was not asking about the specific expression, only generalised, at least that's how I read it.

Comment: Yeah, it's ambiguous what they are asking, @Stu , which is why I made the comment and why I haven't given an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I Mean that is inefficient. you can try following this.

```sql
SELECT [Result]
FROM (SELECT Cast(DateDiff(milliseconds, col1, col2) / DateDiff(milliseconds, col3, col4) as int as [Result] FROM [sometable]) as temp
WHERE [Result] > 4
```

Comment: *"I Mean that is inefficient"* Why? How is what you've provided "more efficient"? It (likely) will result in the same query plan. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RkZ53Lz-)